# Verify if no more interations on a particular method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to do: check if `error` is invoked once with particular argument, but I don't care if other methods are called on the same mock.

```
final Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);

//code under test
logger.debug("Something");//I don't care if it's here
logger.error("Boo");// must be one
//logger.error("Baa");// must fail if un-comment
logger.info("Stuff");//I don't care if it's here


//assertions
verify(logger, times(1)).error("Boo");
???verify(logger, never()).error(anyString());// Wrong solution
???verifyNoMoreInteractions(logger);// Wrong solution
```

In other words, I want to verify how errors are reported, but I don't mind about debug and info.

How can I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't just `verify(logger, times(1)).error("Boo");` do it?

Comment: @dty It will not fail if `logger.error("Baa")` is un-commented, but I want to.

Comment: Sorry, did not catch that. In that case you should take a look at Matchers class. You can check that it is called with "Boo" once and never when argument is not equal "Boo".

Comment: @dty Do you suggest something like`verify(logger, never()).error(not(eq("Boo")));`? Yes... this could be a solution, but I would like to have something more strong, such as `verify(logger, neverAgain()).error(nothingMore()));`...

Comment: Are you saying you want error to be run exactly once, regardless of if it's "Boo" or not (IE: `error("Boo")` followed by `error("Boo")` also results in a failure)?  If so, wouldn't `verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());` do what you want?

Comment: If you're looking to ensure that error is run exactly once, and it's run with "Boo", simply combine the two: `verify(logger, times(1)).error("Boo");` followed by `verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());` (or use the never-not-equal verify statement you came up with above).  In English: "verify that error was called once with `"Boo"`, and 1 time total".

Comment: @Ironcache `error(anyString())` didn't work for me, probably I've done something wrong. If you have a working example, show it.

Comment: @kan The examples I gave should be working examples.  A better way of pursuing this would be to explain what you mean by "didn't work for you"?  Note that the example I gave is different than what's in your example code.  `verify(logger, never()).error(anyString());` will not work, as calling `error("Boo")` alone will lead to failure.

Comment: As a disclaimer, I don't currently have access to a system with Mockito on it, so I can't verify that the examples I've provided function. It's possible I'm mis-remembering Mockito's operation, but if you try to put `verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());` after your current `verify(...)` statement, I'm pretty sure that, provided I understand the question, it'll do what you want (note that it's `times(1)`, not `never()`).

Comment: @Ironcache Oh, good idea about `times(1)`. Not perfect (as I planned to put this verify into tearDown), but I could introduce a counter of how much errors is expected by a unit test.

Comment: @Ironcache if you convert your comment about `times(1)` into answer, I'll glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In General**

If you want to check that you receive exactly `x` errors but do not care about the text in the error:

```
verify(logger, times(x)).error(anyString());
```

If you want to check that you receive `x` errors total, and that `y` should have the text `foo` and `z` should have the text `bar`:

```
verify(logger, times(x)).error(anyString());
verify(logger, times(y)).error("foo");
verify(logger, times(z)).error("bar");
// ... (potentially other cases)
```

**In Context**

So, for the example you provided, if you do not care about the error text, it would look like:

```
verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());
```

If you do care about the error text (IE: you want exactly 1 "Boo", and 1 total error):

```
verify(logger, times(1)).error("Boo");
verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());
```

As Jeff pointed out, the count parameter can be neglected if you are only looking for exactly one occurance.

Answer (score 1):

`times(1)` is the default behavior for `verify`, so `verify(logger).error("Boo");` should be sufficient. Mockito is designed on [a philosophy of "nice mocks"](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-vs-EasyMock#differences) that allow unexpected operations, so if you hold to that, it shouldn't matter whether it's called otherwise.

If you do want to check other calls, as you listed in the comments, you can use [`not`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#not(T)) and `never`:

```
verify(logger).error("Boo");
verify(logger, never()).error(not(eq("Boo")));
```

Or just get all calls with an [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to confirm:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> logCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
verify(logger).error(logCaptor.capture());
assertEquals("Boo", logCaptor.getValue());
```

Comment: `not` is not so good solution in common case. Just imagine if `error` would have several arguments or I would need to verify several `error` calls. `verify(logger, times(howManyErrorsIExpect)).error(any()...)` is easier to use.